# QML MouseArea, trigger and propagate events

Tags: qt, qml, mouseevent, mousearea

I have a QML component with buttons, ... in it. I put a MouseArea which covers this entire component because I need to execute an action wherever I click on the component. However, I also want to execute the action behind the MouseArea.

For example, if I click on a button in the component, I want to execute the MouseArea action and then the button action.

```
Item {

  Button{
    anchors: ...
    onClicked: console.info("Button clicked")
  }

  MouseArea{
    anchors.fill: parent
    propagateComposedEvents: true
    onClicked: console.info("MouseArea clicked")
  }
}
```

If propagateComposedEvents: true, then MouseArea onClicked is not executed, but Button onClicked is. If false, MouseArea is executed but not Button onClicked.

I want to have both MouseArea (first) and Button (second) signal onClicked to be executed.

Comment: I think you can just call `buttonId.clicked()` in reaction to the clicked-signal of the `MouseArea`

Comment: Indeed, it could be the solution but I don't have only one button. I have much more components behind the MouseArea and I can't put each action inside the MouseArea clicked signal.

Comment: Then, maybe, describe what you actually want to achieve. Because maybe, the MouseArea is not your solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set the accepted property of the mouse to false.

```
Item {

  Button{
    anchors: ...
    onClicked: console.info("Button clicked")
  }

  MouseArea{
    anchors.fill: parent
    propagateComposedEvents: true
    onClicked: {
        console.info("MouseArea clicked");
        mouse.accepted =false;
  }
}
```

From [MouseArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#propagateComposedEvents-prop) documentation:

> If propagateComposedEvents is set to true, then composed events will
>   be automatically propagated to other MouseAreas in the same location
>   in the scene. Each event is propagated to the next enabled MouseArea
>   beneath it in the stacking order, propagating down this visual
>   hierarchy until a MouseArea accepts the event. Unlike pressed events,
>   composed events will not be automatically accepted if no handler is
>   present.

If you want to exclusively catch mouse click on one of them, just move the MouseArea under Button regarding its z level. Or, just move its definition before the Button.

```
Item {
  MouseArea{
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: console.info("MouseArea clicked")
  }

  Button{
    anchors: ...
    onClicked: console.info("Button clicked")
  }
}
```

OR:

```
Item {
  Button{
    anchors: ...
    onClicked: console.info("Button clicked")
    z: 1
  }

  MouseArea{
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: console.info("MouseArea clicked")
    z: 0
  }
}
```