# QML forward mouse events to the parent

Tags: qt, event-handling, qml, mouseevent, qquickitem

I have `TableView` inside another `Item` that have `MouseArea`. How can I pass all mouse events to the parent of the `TableView` (or in another words, make it transparent for mouse events) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QML MouseArea, trigger and propagate events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624235/qml-mousearea-trigger-and-propagate-events)

Comment: If you're having clashing issues between MouseArea and other components, then, try using TapHandler/DragHandler instead.

Comment: There is also the `interactive` property, set if to False to have it not react to mouse events (more like a GridLayout, that you where after in your previous SO question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the mouse events just in the parent item, stack the mouse area above the table.

With `propagateComposedEvents` you can achieve, that both gets the mouse event.

Small example:

```
Rectangle {

    color: "red"
    anchors.fill: parent

    Rectangle {
        color: "green"
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 20

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: console.log("green")
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        // if you activate this, both mouse areas get the click
        propagateComposedEvents: true

        onClicked: (mouse) => {
                       // true: only one mouse area is getting the event if propagateComposedEvents is set
                       // false: both mouse areas are getting the event if propagateComposedEvents is set
                       mouse.accepted = false;
                       console.log("red")
                   }
    }
}
```